# Solving for the particular solution of linear differential equations if the equality is unusual

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking a course on ordinary differential equations and I am asked to find the particular solution of $$y''-10y'+25y=-16.5e^{5t}/(t^2+1)$$

I would assume that this sort of problem would involve using the ahhnihilator method because that is the main method that we have used so far. However, we have only seem annihilators of the form $$[(D-a)^2+b^2]^m$$ and I am really unsure about how to solve for the solution. What is the general method to use here?

Thank you

Comment: Smells like [*Variation of Parameters*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx), see Example $2$.

Comment: Have you learnt the inverse operator. Method ? It's the easiest method but isn't widely taught for some reason.

Comment: @user230452 Maybe the reason is because it is easy to [err on it](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1672783/97236)?

Answer (score 2):

Using $y=z e^{5t}$ makes the differential equation $$e^{5 t} z''=-\frac{33}2 \frac{e^{5 t} }{t^2+1}$$ That is to say $$z''=-\frac{33}2 \frac{1 }{t^2+1}$$ $$z'=-\frac{33}2 \tan^{-1}(t)+c_1$$ $$z=-\frac{33}2 t\tan^{-1}(t)+\frac{33}{4} \log \left(t^2+1\right)+c_1 t+c_2$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried guessing what the annihilator method was, but I guessed wrongly. However, I did solve the differential equation. First I found a function that would be annihilated by $(D-5)^2$, that is $te^{5t}$. Then I multiplied by an unknown function so that $y_1(t)=u(t)\cdot te^{5t}$. Then
$$\begin{align}(D-5)y_1 & =u^{\prime}te^{5t}+ue^{5t}+5ute^{5t}-5ute^{5t}\\
 & =u^{\prime}te^{5t}+ue^{5t}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}(D-5)^2y_1 & =u^{\prime\prime}t^{5t}+2u^{\prime}e^{5t}+5ue^{5t}+5u^{\prime}te^{5t}-5ue^{5t}-5u^{\prime}te^{5t}\\
 & =u^{\prime\prime}te^{5t}+2u^{\prime}e^{5t}=-\frac{33}2\frac{e^{5t}}{t^1+1}\end{align}$$
Then if we let $v=u^{\prime}$,
$$v^{\prime}+\frac2tv=-\frac{33}{2t(t^2+1)}$$
The integrating factor is
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac2tdt}=e^{2\ln t}=t^2$$
So
$$\frac d{dt}\left(t^2v\right)=t^2v^{\prime}+2tv=-\frac{33t}{2(t^2+1)}$$
Our first integral is then
$$t^2v=t^2u^{\prime}=-\frac{33}4\ln(t^2+1)+c_1$$
Or
$$u^{\prime}=-\frac{33}{4t^2}\ln(t^2+1)+\frac{c_1}{t^2}$$
Integrating by parts,
$$\begin{align}u & =\frac{33}{4t}\ln(t^2+1)-\frac{33}2\int\frac1{t^1+1}dt-\frac{c_1}t\\
 & =\frac{33}{4t}\ln(t^2+1)-\frac{33}2\tan^{-1}t-\frac{c_1}t+c_2\end{align}$$
So we have
$$y(t)=u(t)\cdot te^{5t}=\left\{\frac{33\ln(t^2+1)}{4}-\frac{33t\tan^{-1}t}{2}-c_1+c_2t\right\}e^{5t}$$